# Animation in a Qt 2D pathfinding game

Tags: c++, qt, 2d-games

I'm making a 2D grid based game in Qt.

When clicking on a square in a grid the player moves to that square following a path calculated with an A* algoritm. However I would like to be able to animate this. So instead of immediately going to the goal the player has to go from square (node) to square until it reaches the goal at a speed that the user can set.

**Question**: What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Your A* algorithm outputs a list/vector of points, I guess? Do you allow diagonal moves? Is the speed constant? Are there any other interactions possible during moving to the target? Also, how does your current player class look like? Does it have a position property or something similar?

Comment: No I don't allow diagonal moves. The speed should be able to be set. There are no other possible interactions (but maybe there should he a pause/play but that's not a must). The player is just an extension of a QGraphicsObject. It receives a list of directions it must follow to reach it's destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd design this similar to the following:

```
class Player : public QObject {
    ...
    QPoint pos;
    QList<QPoint> path;
    QPropertyAnimation posAnimation;
};
```

Define `pos` as a `Q_PROPERTY`. This enables you to use `QPropertyAnimation` to define an animation on this value for animating the movement **between two adjacent points**. After the animation is done, `take()` one point from the path and reconfigure the animation, giving you an animation along the **whole path**.

Use a slot `animationFinished()` in the Player class to provide the next point to the animation.

To start such an animation, fill the path with the values (in a function `move(QList<QPoint> path)` or similar), set the values of the animation and start it.

These code snippets should help you:

```
// in constructor:
posAnimation.setPropertyName("pos");
posAnimation.setTargetObject(this);
connect(&posAnimation, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(animationFinished()));

// in the slot:
if(!path.empty()) {
    posAnimation.setStartValue(pos());
    posAnimation.setEndValue(path.takeFirst());
    posAnimation.start();
}
```

To define `pos` as a property, you have to define two slots: A reading and a writing function, also known as a getter and a setter:

```
class Player : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QPoint pos READ pos WRITE setPos) // define meta-property "pos"
    ...
public slots:
    QPoint pos() const; // getter
    void setPos(QPoint p); // setter
private:
    QPoint m_pos; // private member
};
```

```
QPoint Player::pos() const {
    return m_pos;
}
void Player::setPos(QPoint pos) {
    m_pos = pos;
}
```

The `Q_PROPERTY` line just declares a *meta-property*. This has nothing to do with C++, but Qt's meta object compiler parses this line and adds an entry to the internal property list. Then, you can say `player->property("pos")` to access the position instead of `player->pos()`. You may wonder why this is useful. It's useful whenever you only want to pass around a property *name* as a string, like to tell the QPropertyAnimation which property to animate. Another scenario is when using scripting like QML. Then you define properties all over your classes. You can read more about meta-properties in the Qt documentation: [The Property System](http://qt-project.org/doc/properties.html).

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke I added a paragraph in the answer.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke Just to clarify. There are 4 things now. A private member to hold the actual value, a getter, a setter and a property declaration. The name of the property declaration is to be read as a string, not as a C++ symbol. The other three have to have *different names*. The property can be named as you like. I prefer to name the getter as the property name, the setter by prefixing `set` (+ starting with a capital letter) and the member by prefixing `m_`, but this is just a convention. The Q_PROPERTY syntax is explained in the documentation I have linked. Good luck! :)

Comment: Have I understood you correctly? by defining setPos I can no longer use the property of setPos of QGraphicsItem right? So giving it another name might be a better solution then?

Comment: Ah correct, if you inherit from `QGraphicsItem`, then give it another name, like gridPos or position. For consistency, use the same name for setter, getter, ..., with the prefixes as I said. In the setter, you can then also set the position of the graphics item, like `setPos(m_gridPos * cellSize)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the demo of the tower defense game [Squaby](http://games.v-play.net/squaby/) made with the [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net) engine. You can access the full source code here: [Squaby](http://v-play.net/doc/demos-squaby.html).
V-Play provides you with game components for path finding and more ([API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html)).